# Yii2 как создать sql комманду на нативном подключении?

Tags: база-данных, yii2

Команду делаю так:

```
$db = new \yii\db\Connection([
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ]);

db()->createCommand("UPDATE `cms_profile` SET `UserName`='$model->Fname $model->Lname',`Mobile1`=$model->Mobile,`Mail`='$model->Mail',`ProfileImg`='db.jpg' WHERE `Mail`='$this->Mail'")->execute();
```

Как использовать родное подключение к бд указанной в конфиге фреймворка вместо создания объекта **$db**?

Comment: `Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->execute()` или вы про что? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-dao.html#creating-db-connections

Comment: именно это я имел ввиду, я так пробовал, выводит ругань что не найден такой метод. у меня yii2 basic может поэтому?

Comment: Нет, не поэтому ... Какой именно метод не найден: `createCommand()`?

Comment: все нашел ошибку, опечатку сделал, все работает, вы правы так и надо делать, сделайте ваш комментарий ответом засчитаю за правильный ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из [документации](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/db-dao.md#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-):

> Так как подключение к БД часто нужно в нескольких местах, распространённой практикой является его настройка как компонента приложения:

```
return [
    // ...
    'components' => [
        // ...
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
    ],
    // ...
];
```

Следовательно, раз это компонент приложения, то мы можем получить доступ  к нему так:

```
Yii::$app->db
```

---

В вашем случае код будет выглядеть подобным образом:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand(<SQL-запрос>)->execute()
```